# "Merci" meaning "please" or "veuillez"

Tags: grammaire, sens

So far I've only come across with the "thank you" meaning of *merci*. Recently, I saw this phrase:

> *Merci de vous enregistrer au moins une heure avant de partir.*

Which translates to

> *Please register at least one hour before leaving.*

The original has roughly the same meaning as "*Veuillez vous enregistrer au moins une heure avant de partir.*".
When can I use "Merci" that way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word please can be written in more than one way in French, which all have small differences in meaning. It's why you see the word « Merci » used that way.

All the forms in the sentence example you gave:

- Merci de...
- Prière de...
- Je vous prie de...
- Veuillez...

The *vouvoiement* makes the sentence that way, it's extra-polite. It's a concept that doesn't exist in English I think.

So as I said, in the sentence you could swap the word « Merci » with « Prière ».

Example:

> Prière de vous enregistrer au moins une heure avant de partir.

The sentence means the same thing, but the word « Merci » is softer in tone, where in the example I gave it's a more direct way to say it.

Comment: "Thank you for..." is used in English too, with a noun phrase, e.g. Thank you for not dropping litter. It implies an expectation of "doing the right thing", and may also be seen as being slightly less abrupt than "Please..."

Answer (score 0):

*Merci de* expresses a [recommendation](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/recommander) [c.f. A.2.a)] whereas *veuillez* implies an [injunction](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/injonction/substantif).

Both sentences formulate a request: [recommendation/injunction](https://cnrtl.fr/synonymie/prescription).

Answer (score -12):

Using this would be polite formula is not recommended in the context you present; it is barely acceptable as an introduction of routine requests in application forms  and the like. It is otherwise considered as manipulative and inelegant, not polite: you extend thanks to someone before you've even had a reaction to what you just asked ([non au merci de…](https://www.ithaquecoaching.com/articles/incivilites-travail-merci-de-11734.html)).

Here are more recommendations not to use this formula.

https://www.helloworkplace.fr/merci-de-ne-plus-ecrire-merci-de-dans-vos-mails-et-autres-impolitesses-au-bureau/

https://optimiz.me/2-formues-de-politesses-a-proscrire-de-vos-e-mails/

Comment: I don't get why you believe this formula should not be recommended in this context. *Merci de vous enregistrer au moins une heure avant (le départ)* is definitely an order, not a mild suggestion.

Comment: @jlliagre I'd consider that a routine request, which really is not a true request but an advice; as such (pseudo request) it is not very objectionnable as I see it. However, a proper communication for this is "Il est pratiquement nécessaire que vous fassiez votre enregistrement au moins une heure à l'avance." and then if a "merci" is in order it can only emanate from the persons who have been advised. Those thanks can very often be felt as mere  "customer pampering" from merchandisers eager to please their clients.

Comment: "Il est pratiquement nécessaire que vous fassiez votre enregistrement au moins une heure à l'avance" is very unidiomatic...

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne vois pas ce qui est non idiomatique: "il est nécessaire de" est idiomatique et "pratiquement nécessaire" l'est aussi.

Comment: Je dit souvent a mes enfants, "Merci d'enlever vous chaussure avant d'entrée" en exemple, donc a mon avis c'est une phrase vraiment typique Française dans mon coin de pays. Le Merci est toujours suivi du de dans ces contextes là quand c'est pour dire "please" comme le OP le demande. mais je peut comprende en email comme vos lien disent, mais le contexte email me semblent plus pour le bureau vs un autre employé

Comment: @yagmoth555 Oui, je comprends bien que des habitudes acquises depuis un certain temps deviennent seconde nature et que l'on ait du mal à considérer qu'elles puissent n'être pas tout à fait idéales. Je pense personnellement que chaque fois que l'on change une tournure de langue pour une tournure qui est plus en harmonie avec la logique, on améliore la langue et on rend la façon de penser de ceux qui l'utilisent plus pure.

Comment: @LPH On a déjà eu cette conversation de multiples fois. Pour une raison qui te regarde, tu ne veux pas reconnaître ton manque d'expérience pratique de la langue française. Que tu ne voie pas ce qui cloche avec *il est pratiquement nécessaire que vous fassiez votre enregistrement...* en est une nouvelle preuve.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Oui *Merci d'enlever vos chaussures avant d'entrer* est parfaitement idiomatique est n'a rien d'inacceptable, de "manipulatif", d'inélégant ou d'impoli. C'est bien d'une directive qu'il s'agit, comme dans la phrase de l'OP.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne pense pas que les trois sources que je cite fassent preuve d'un manque d'expérience pratique de la langue française et je crois devoir parler  plutôt selon leurs recommandations qu'autrement.

Comment: Je ne partage pas les idées moralisatrices et méprisantes des trois sites en question mais mon commentaire n'avait rien à voir avec eux. Il concernait ta phrase *Il est pratiquement nécessaire que vous fassiez votre enregistrement...*

Comment: @jlliagre Je n'utilise pas le mot "moralisateur" dans son sens péjoratif; il trouve son origine  évidemment dans un mépris  semi avoué de la morale.

Comment: Il ne faut pas confondre les termes idiomatique, registre et contexte. En tout cas,  la première phrase de cette réponse n'est sûrement pas idiomatique en anglais. Pourquoi les questions si simples posées par le débutants causent-elles autant de débats inutiles et stériles? Je me pose la question assez souvent dans ce forum.