# "Merci de remplir le formulaire" - s'agit-il d'une instruction ou d'un remerciement ?

Tags: usage

"Thank you for filling in the form" is an expression of thanks but translates to "Merci de remplir le formulaire" which sounds like an instruction to do so. Is it necessary to change it to "Merci d'avoir rempli le formulaire" to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: See also: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42589/merci-meaning-please-or-veuillez/42592#42592

Answer (score 3):

If *Merci de remplir le formulaire* appears after the form has been filled, there shouldn't be any ambiguity. But to be completely clear you might prefer:

- *Merci de (bien vouloir) remplir le formulaire ci-dessous* if you want to give an instruction, i.e. at the top of the form.
- *Merci d'avoir rempli le formulaire* at the end of the form, i.e. after the form has been filled.

Comment: Pas d'ambiguité, certes, mais une phrase qui ne correspond pas à ce qu'on veut communiquer.

Comment: Ce ne serait pas l'essence même de l'ambiguïté, si ce que tu dis ne correspond pas à ce que tu veux dire?

Comment: @Frank … c'est une invitation péremptoire https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/peremptoire

Comment: From the tense alone, "*merci de remplir [...]*" is an instruction. It can't be used after the form has been filled.

Answer (score 2):

As a native French speaker, I only understand "Merci de remplir le formulaire" as a polite command, equivalent to "Merci d'avance de remplir le formulaire": I believe it accurately translates "Thanks in advance for filling in the form", *certainly not* "Thanks for filling in the form".

The latter would translate to "Merci d'avoir rempli le formulaire". Conversely, I doubt if native English speakers would ever consider writing "Thanks for having filled in the form"; it looks exotic to say the least. There must be many, many examples of the English language favoring the present tense when the French demands a past infinitive.

Answer (score 0):

“Merci de remplir le formulaire” can be used in both meanings, and just has to be taken with the context. When put at the end, or after you fill out a form, it would be synonym to thanks. If you intend this meaning, you might want to put your sentence in the passé composé:

> Merci d’avoir rempli le formulaire.

This said, when put for example in a mail, with a link to the form attached, it more so is used as an instruction, or an order (if extreme). If you want to use it as an instruction, you can say

> Merci en avance de remplir ce formulaire

or

> Merci de bien vouloir remplir ce formulaire

I Hope this helps!

Comment: *Merci **par** avance*. ***En**  avance* veut dire « avant le moment prévu » (« Le train est arrivé en avance »).

Answer (score -1):

Votre question est intéressante, car elle fait apparaître la dérive, si l'on peut dire, qu'a subi le langage depuis une cinquantaine d'années  :
En effet, à l'origine on doit "prier" quelqu'un de faire quelque chose et le "remercier" après que la chose a été faite.
Mais au cours du 20e siècle, la formulation "je vous prie" fut de plus en plus employée sous une forme ironique, et devint finalement comme un ordre ou une menace. Par suite, on n'osa plus l'employer dans son sens originel par peur d'être entendu au sens désobligeant du terme.
Le remerciement n'ayant pas subi cette dérive ironique, one se mit alors à l'utiliser pour prier quelqu'un de faire quelque chose: "prière de ..." devint "merci de...". En soi c'est pourtant une faute de langage, et il faut admettre que cet usage est récent, 40 à 50 ans tout au plus...